# Keep getting an error with the code for this equation!

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations

I've been trying to get this to work, but I keep getting errors saying `Paragraph ended before \end was complete.` I can't see where the issue is though. Could someone help?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}


When hydrogen is the fuel used:
\begin{equation*}
U_t=2249\ln \frac{1\times10^{6}{1\times10^6-424.6t}}
\end{equation*}

When kerosene is the fuel used:
\begin{equation*}
U_t=1737\ln \frac{1\times10^{6}{1\times10^6-1022t}}
\end{equation*}

When hydrazine is the fuel used:
\begin{equation*}
U_t=2025\ln \frac{1\times10^{6}{1\times10^6-1004t}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a problem with `\frac`, it needs two parameters. And you have one in the code.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realized I'd made a mistake with the braces over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, there is something wrong with the "Fraction". A fraction is created using the `\frac{numerator}{denominator}` command. See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Fractions_and_Binomials) for some excellent hints.

Otherwise, try it with:

```
When hydrogen is the fuel used:
\begin{equation*}
U_t=2249\ln\frac{1\times10^6}{1\times10^{6-424t}}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've changed it. Do you have any tips for avoiding mistakes with braces in the future, or is it just a matter of remaining vigilant?